# why does pre-dispatch in SignedExtension require you to call validate?

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions

I am trying to understand how to develop an attack vector for when the pre-dispatch function leaves out the same checks in the validate function.

Can you please help me understand what the attack vector looks like?

Comment: To add to this question, in trying to understand what predispatch (by calling validate) is meant to do, we took a signed extension and set pre_dispatch to return always Ok(Default::default()), then submitted a transaction that we knew would fail and there did not seem to be a difference of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you need the same logic for checking the validity in both is that a node is not required to call [validate_transaction](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L538-L570). This function (which is called [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1839-L1847)) is only an optimization for the node to reject transactions early and to clean up the tx pool. The runtime itself needs to ensure that when a transaction is applied to the state, that the transaction is valid. This means that the signature is correct, that the nonce = current_nonce + 1 etc. All these checks are there to ensure that transactions are valid and the runtime can only trust "itself".